# android - Set a TextView exactly specific part of the photo?

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, android-relativelayout

I need to set a TextView exactly specific part of the photo I am using from bellow xml but i set all of size manual I need to be dynamic for different size mobile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/list_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CallCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/list_back" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CallCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with a frameLayout ? set the gravity to `right | top` and it should work on every device

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CallCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can the person who disliked my answer tell me why at least ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `RelativeLayout` as root, you can use `layout_alignParentX` properties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/list_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CallCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But if you don't need, I recommend to use a `FrameLayout` as root to avoid a double call to `invalidate()` from `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CallCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```